# Jersey resource structure

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to use sub-resources to enable better grouping but one of my resources is a sub-resource of two different resources. For example if I have a parent like so parents/1 and i also have children at parents/1/children/1, I want to be able to access the information belonging to the parent or  a specific child. Something like /parents/1/info and parents/1/children/1/info. What would be the best way to implement this using Jersey 2.x ? I've tried to do so, but I noticed then both 'info' endpoints end up at the same method, and I would need to check the request context in order to determine how to process the request. Is there a better way to do this without dependency injection/passing around path parameters ?

Edit:

```
@Path("parents")
public class ParentResource {
    @Path("{parent-id}/children")
    public ChildResource getChild(@PathParam("parent-id") String parentId) {
        return new ChildResource(parentId);
    }

    @Path("{parent-id}/info")
    public InfoResource getInfo(@PathParam("parent-id") String parentId) {
        return new InfoResource(parentId);
    }
}

public class ChildResource {
    private String parentId;

    public ChildResource(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    @Path("{child-id}/info")
    public InfoResource getInfo(@PathParam("child-id") String childId) {
        return new InfoResource(parentId, childId);
    }
}

public class InfoResource {
    private String parentId;
    private String childId;

    public InfoResource(String parentId) {
        this(parentId, null);
    }

    public InfoResource(String parentId, String childId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    @GET
    public String getInfo() {
        if (childId == null)
            return "Info of parent";
        return "Info of child";
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed to share your code resp. what you have done so far. Please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article.

Comment: @zyexal Sorry about that ! I knew I was forgetting something. I told myself I was going to add a code snippet but I must have forgot about it.

Comment: Afaig there is nothing like return-value-resource-path-chaining available, even if it's a nice suggestion. You will need to declare the path within a single resource class `@Path("parents")` & `@GET @Path("{parent-id}/children/{child-id}/info")`. Upvote for the suggestion.

Comment: @zyexal In that case, do you think it would be better to get rid of InfoResource altogether and have the respective `@GET` method within of ParentResource and ChildResource ?

Comment: Yap, at least I would do so.

Comment: And if there are multiple methods shared by both the ParentResource and ChildResource ? Eg. `POST`, `GET` for specific, etc. What's the threshold for separating it vs. abstracting it into its own resource class ?